# Odoo Invoice number - validating an invoice isn't re-using the internal_number if exists

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, invoice

Dears,

Usually, Upon Validating an invoice, it takes a new sequence from sequence (e.g. SAJ/%(year)s/), and in case that invoice has an internal_number (case of canceled invoice set to draft), it should use its internal_number. But the unwanted behavior now is when validating a draft invoice - previously canceled  - the system generates new sequence number. I need to re-use the existing internal number.

Thank you,

Odoo 8

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from a configuration in the Journal (account.journal) . Every time I validate an invoice it will create new Journal entry with new Sequence number (e.g. SAJ/2017/55545), so I unchecked the Autopost Created Move. Now. when I attemp to validate an invoice already canceled it will use it's existing internal_number as invoice number.

========================

## Accounting-> Invoice -> Sales Journal (account.journal) -> untick Autopost Created Move

Scenario:

-create invoice, INV number N1 is assigned to inv

-state goes to OPEN

-cancel the invoice then set to draft: the number disappear from the interface

-validate the invoice -> new number became the same existing N1